# Округление чисел с плавающей точкой в js и c#

Tags: javascript, c#

Для примера возьмем число 170844.29499999998. С помощью этой функции на js можно округлять числа с плавающей точкой:

```
function round(value, decimals) {
  return Number(Math.round(value + 'e' + decimals) + 'e-' + decimals);
}
```

применив функцию:

```
round(170844.29499999998, 1)
170844.3
round(170844.29499999998, 2)
170844.29
round(170844.29499999998, 3)
170844.295
```

Если округлять на стороне C#:

```
Math.Round(170844.29499999998, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
170844,3
Math.Round(170844.29499999998, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) <--??????
170844,3
Math.Round(170844.29499999998, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
170844,295
```

В коде происходят сравнения, поэтому мне нужно что бы результат при округлении был одинаков. Есть ли способ пофиксить это? Была идея делать так: `Math.Round(number - 0.001, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)` либо так: `round(number + 0.001, 2)`, но я не уверен, как это отразится на приложении.

Comment: Потому что C# округляет правильно, а ваш код на js - не правильно.

Comment: _происходят сравнения_ - а вот от этого лучше отказаться. Вернее, не сравнивать вещественные числа напрямую, а только с указанием погрешности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, такой способ округления будет более правильным.

```js
function round(value, decimals) {
  let dec = Math.pow(10, decimals);
  return Math.round(value * dec) / dec;
}
const n = 170844.29499999998;
console.log(round(n, 1));
console.log(round(n, 2));
console.log(round(n, 3));
```